# How to replace first few spaces in cell with other values

Tags: excel, vba

I have date values which are shown as "01 01 1970 12:00" for example. Since the date uses spaces and not "-" or "/", excel does not recognize it as a date value.

Using
`Range = Replace(Range, " ", "/", 1, 2)`
or
`Range = Replace(Range, " ", "/")`
returns a type mismatch error

Using
`Range.Replace what:=" ", replacement:="/", lookat:=xlPart`
works, but it also replaces the last space and turns the value to "01/01/1970/12:00" which i do not want. It is supposed to return as a date format.

Comment: You may try `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/",2)," ","/",1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist value of Funtion `Replace` is `String`

So You must change `Range` to value of `Cell`:

Ex: Value must replace at Cell(1,1)

```
Range = Replace(Range, " ", "/", 1, 2)
```

To:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, " ", "/", 1, 2)
```

Comment: Right now it's looping through columns as such

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D")
    Cell = Replace(Cell, " ", "/", 1, 2)
Next Cell

but it returns a mismatch error. If I change the columns to a range, no error occurs, but the cells do not change either. Nothing happens

Comment: Your "Cell" is a Array. You must change to "For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("C:D").Cells
  Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, " ", "/", 1, 2)
Next Cell"

Answer (score 1):

### Replace Date Separator

**Excel Formula (`SUBSTITUTE`)**

```vb
Sub ReplaceDateSeparator()

    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "C2:D2"
    Const SearchSeparator As String = " "
    Const ReplaceSeparator As String = "/"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

    rg.Value = ws.Evaluate("=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" & rg.Address _
        & ",""" & SearchSeparator & """,""" & ReplaceSeparator _
        & """,1),""" & SearchSeparator & """,""" & ReplaceSeparator & """,1)")

End Sub
```

**VBA (`Split/Join`)**

```vb
Sub ReplaceDateSeparatorVbaTEST()

    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "C2:D2"
    Const SearchSeparator As String = " "
    Const ReplaceSeparator As String = "/"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

    ReplaceDateSeparatorVba rg, SearchSeparator, ReplaceSeparator

End Sub

Sub ReplaceDateSeparatorVba( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        Optional ByVal SearchSeparator As String = " ", _
        Optional ByVal ReplaceSeparator As String = "/")
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    If rCount + cCount = 2 Then ' one cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            cValue = Data(r, c)
            If Not IsError(cValue) Then ' exclude error values
                Arr = Split(Data(r, c), SearchSeparator, 3)
                Data(r, c) = Join(Arr, ReplaceSeparator)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```